# javascript for changing image based on php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div style="margin-left:5%;width:5%;float:left;margin-right:10%;">
  <img src="./1.png" id="imgstatus"/>
</div>
<div style="width:80%;float:left;">
  <h3>Your transaction was <?php echo $message; ?> ! Your transaction reference number for any furthur communication is <?php echo $cust_ref_no; ?> .</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

I have this html. All I want is javascript which chnages the img src to `<img src="./1.png" />` `if $message='succes'` and `<img src="./2.png"/>` when `$message='failed'`.

Comment: Are you looking to display or hide the image based on the value of the $message variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="margin-left:5%;width:5%;float:left;margin-right:10%;">
  <img src="<?php

  if($message == 'success')
  {
      echo 'success.jpg';
  }
  else
  {
      echo 'failed.jpg';
  }

  ?>" id="imgstatus"/>
</div>
<div style="width:80%;float:left;">
  <h3>Your transaction was <?php echo $message; ?> ! Your transaction reference number for any furthur communication is <?php echo $cust_ref_no; ?> .</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ternary operator to minimize code length.

```
<div style="margin-left:5%;width:5%;float:left;margin-right:10%;">
  <img src="<?php echo ($message == 'success' ? 'success.jpg' : 'failed.jpg'); ?>" id="imgstatus"/>
</div>
<div style="width:80%;float:left;">
  <h3>Your transaction was <?php echo $message; ?> ! Your transaction reference number for any furthur communication is <?php echo $cust_ref_no; ?> .</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: and even shorter:

`<img src="<?php=($message == 'success' ? 'success.jpg' : 'failed.jpg'); ?>"/>`